# Inbound Email received in Salesforce Case object is within the character limit however, it is truncated

Tags: email2case

If this question is not permitted here, please delete.

An Inbound Email in Email to Case is within the character limit not exceeding nor within 3,200 Characters. The Body of the eamil is less than 3,200 characters. The attachment is 2 MB and the total email is 2.5 MB.

Email and Text Body of the message is truncated in Message detail of Case showing only 
Words 150
Characters (no spaces) 652
Characters (with spaces) 801

Can you please help me point out what is wrong with it and what is causing the truncation, though it is within the Salesforce email limit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally users manage to include special characters in their text which have an influence on the way things are displayed. Have you checked for anything unusual in the whitespace characters?

Comment: Please provide sample or all samples for special characters that you are pertaining to? I noticed in the email that after first paragraph there are three spaces then second paragraph follows.